# How to use code-generated SOAP client?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I need to make a Soap client in java for [the EU tax id service](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tin/checkTinService.wsdl).

I mamanged to generate the code from the WSDL using wsimport. My problem is that cannot figure out how to use it. More specifically, how do I make a Soap call to the service so I can validate the tax id?

I tried even multiple ways using code generated from SOAP UI, code from Intellij, etc. They are all quite different and I am kinda stuck into this. Could anyone light me up, please? Thanks!

It seems rather difficult for me and I already spent so many hours on this without a result. I have also tried al the tutorials I could find on google. I am guessing an answer on this would help many in the future.

Here's the generated code:

CheckTinService.java:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "checkTinService", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin", wsdlLocation = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tin/checkTinService.wsdl")
public class CheckTinService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL CHECKTINSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException CHECKTINSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName CHECKTINSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin", "checkTinService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tin/checkTinService.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        CHECKTINSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        CHECKTINSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public CheckTinService() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), CHECKTINSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public CheckTinService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), CHECKTINSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public CheckTinService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, CHECKTINSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public CheckTinService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, CHECKTINSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public CheckTinService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public CheckTinService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns CheckTinPortType
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "checkTinPort")
    public CheckTinPortType getCheckTinPort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin", "checkTinPort"), CheckTinPortType.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns CheckTinPortType
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "checkTinPort")
    public CheckTinPortType getCheckTinPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin", "checkTinPort"), CheckTinPortType.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (CHECKTINSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw CHECKTINSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return CHECKTINSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }

}
```

CheckTinPortType.java

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;
import eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types.ObjectFactory;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "checkTinPortType", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface CheckTinPortType {


    /**
     * 
     * @param tinNumber
     * @param countryCode
     * @param validStructure
     * @param requestDate
     * @param validSyntax
     */
    @WebMethod
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "checkTin", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types", className = "eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types.CheckTin")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "checkTinResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types", className = "eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types.CheckTinResponse")
    public void checkTin(
        @WebParam(name = "countryCode", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT)
        Holder<String> countryCode,
        @WebParam(name = "tinNumber", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT)
        Holder<String> tinNumber,
        @WebParam(name = "requestDate", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<XMLGregorianCalendar> requestDate,
        @WebParam(name = "validStructure", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<Boolean> validStructure,
        @WebParam(name = "validSyntax", targetNamespace = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<Boolean> validSyntax);

}
```

ObjectFactory.java:

```
import com.exiqon.core.eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types.CheckTin;
import com.exiqon.core.eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types.CheckTinResponse;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link eu.europa.ec.taxud.tin.services.checktin.types.CheckTin }
     * 
     */
    public CheckTin createCheckTin() {
        return new CheckTin();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link CheckTinResponse }
     * 
     */
    public CheckTinResponse createCheckTinResponse() {
        return new CheckTinResponse();
    }

}
```

CheckTinResponse.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="countryCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="tinNumber" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="requestDate" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date"/>
 *         &lt;element name="validStructure" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean"/>
 *         &lt;element name="validSyntax" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "countryCode",
    "tinNumber",
    "requestDate",
    "validStructure",
    "validSyntax"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "checkTinResponse")
public class CheckTinResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String countryCode;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String tinNumber;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar requestDate;
    protected boolean validStructure;
    protected Boolean validSyntax;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the countryCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the countryCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCountryCode(String value) {
        this.countryCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the tinNumber property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTinNumber() {
        return tinNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the tinNumber property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTinNumber(String value) {
        this.tinNumber = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the requestDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getRequestDate() {
        return requestDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the requestDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setRequestDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.requestDate = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the validStructure property.
     * 
     */
    public boolean isValidStructure() {
        return validStructure;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the validStructure property.
     * 
     */
    public void setValidStructure(boolean value) {
        this.validStructure = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the validSyntax property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public Boolean isValidSyntax() {
        return validSyntax;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the validSyntax property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public void setValidSyntax(Boolean value) {
        this.validSyntax = value;
    }

}
```

CheckTin.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="countryCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="tinNumber" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "countryCode",
    "tinNumber"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "checkTin")
public class CheckTin {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String countryCode;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String tinNumber;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the countryCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the countryCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCountryCode(String value) {
        this.countryCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the tinNumber property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTinNumber() {
        return tinNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the tinNumber property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTinNumber(String value) {
        this.tinNumber = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sample client code.

```
public class WsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CheckTinService checkTinService = new CheckTinService();
            CheckTinPortType portType = checkTinService.getPort(CheckTinPortType.class);
            Holder<String> code = new Holder<String>("DE");
            Holder<String> tin = new Holder<String>("12346789");
            Holder<XMLGregorianCalendar> requestDate = new Holder<>();
            Holder<Boolean> validStructure = new Holder<>();
            Holder<Boolean> validSyntax = new Holder<>();
            portType.checkTin(code, tin, requestDate, validStructure, validSyntax);

            System.out.println("requestDate : " + requestDate.value);
            System.out.println("validStructure : " + validStructure.value);
            System.out.println("validSyntax : " + validSyntax.value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

you can also add handler for response soap message.

or from soap UI : send below request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:tin:services:checkTin:types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:checkTin>
         <urn:countryCode>DE</urn:countryCode>
         <urn:tinNumber>12346789</urn:tinNumber>
      </urn:checkTin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem here?

Get a `CheckTinPortType` by calling a properly initialized `CheckTinService`'s `getCheckTinPort()`, and use that to perform the call.

All the necessary classes are generated, you just need to perform the `checkTin()` call now with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman. Can the instance of the CheckTinPortType safely be shared by all users of a webapplication? Or should there be a CheckTinPortType per user, or even one per request?